# Why is the Mesh menu empty?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am new to unreal and am facing a weird problem. I would like to insert a mesh on my character but the mesh menu is completely empty. Below is the image of how it looks.
[image]

As you can see, this blueprint class is derived from a class named 'MainCharacter'. Here is the relevant code snippet.

Implementation (c++) file

```
FPSMesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<USkeletalMeshComponent>(TEXT("Mesh"));
FPSMesh->SetupAttachment(FPSCameraComponent);
```

Header file

```
UPROPERTY(VisibleDefaultsOnly, Category = Mesh)
USkeletalMeshComponent *FPSMesh;
```

The problem started when I switched the USkeletalMeshComponent to a UStaticMeshComponent. I started getting an empty mesh screen. I switched it back to a USkeletalMeshComponent and I am still getting this empty menu.

Any Tips?

Comment: I'm not sure on the canonical way to fix this, but your mesh has serialized out as nullptr. I've a feeling renaming from `Mesh` might work. Alternatively you can represent to Actor and the back to Main character (you will lose any non default settings but it will alm9sr certainly work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the Blueprint and recreating it worked. No idea why.